# Find common members that are in two lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

This may be a duplicate but the closest I could find was [Comparing 2 lists consisting of dictionaries with unique keys in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845369/comparing-2-lists-consisting-of-dictionaries-with-unique-keys-in-python) which did not work for me.

So I have two lists of dictionaries.

```
y = [{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
y = [{'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
```

How do I compare these two lists so my compare results in the intersection of the two lists. I can't convert it to set since it says unhashable type (dict)

Comment: what do you want to be considered when determining the intersection? The keys?  The values?  The key/value pairs?

Comment: from the question, it seems that he means the key-value pairs.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: And how do you define such an "intersection" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question and it's title seem at odds with each other.

The intersection of the 2 lists would be the common elements of both list. The question title requests the elements that are *not* in both lists. Which is it that you want?

For the intersection, it is not very efficient (being O(n^2) in time), but this list comprehension will do it:

```
>>> a = [{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
>>> b = [{'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
>>> [d for d in a if d in b]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
y1 = [{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
y2 = [{'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
print [x for x in y1 if x in y2] # prints [{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

A dict (or list) is not hashable, however, a tuple is. You can convert the list of dicts to a set of tuples. Perform the intersection and then convert back

the code to convert to a set-of-tuples

```
y_tupleset = set(tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in y)
```

the code to convert back the intersected set-of-tuples to a list-of-dicts

```
y_dictlist = [dict(it) for it in list(y_tupleset)]
```

Thus, the full code would be:

```
y0 = [{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
y1 = [{'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]

y0_tupleset = set(tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in y0)
y1_tupleset = set(tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in y1)
y_inter = y0_tupleset.intersection(y1_tupleset)
y_inter_dictlist = [dict(it) for it in list(y_inter)]

print(y_inter_dictlist)
# prints the following line
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}]
```

edit: `d.items()` is valid on python3, for python2, it should be replaced with `d.iteritems()`

Answer (score 0):

Pick your poison:

```
y1 = [{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
y2 = [{'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
y3 = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 6}]

# Returns a list of keys that are in both dictionaries
def intersect_keys(d1, d2):
    return [k for k in d1 if k in d2]

# Returns a list of values that are in both dictionaries
def intersect_vals(d1, d2):
    return [v for v in d1.itervalues() if v in d2.itervalues()]

# Returns a list of (key,value) pairs that are in both dictionaries
def intersect_pairs(d1, d2):
    return [(k,v) for (k,v) in d1.iteritems() if k in d2 and d2[k] == v]


print(intersect_keys(*y1))      # ['a', 'c', 'b']
print(intersect_vals(*y1))      # [3]
print(intersect_pairs(*y1))     # []

print(intersect_keys(*y2))      # ['a', 'c', 'b']
print(intersect_vals(*y2))      # []
print(intersect_pairs(*y2))     # []

print(intersect_keys(*y3))      # ['a', 'c', 'b']
print(intersect_vals(*y3))      # [2]
print(intersect_pairs(*y3))     # [('b', 2)]
```

Note: the examples compare the two elements of the `y*` list, which was how I interpreted your question.  You could of course use something like:

```
print(intersect_pairs(y1[0], y2[0]))
```

To compute the intersection the first dictionary in the `y1` and `y2` lists.