# Compare two List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries:

```
list_1 = [
           {'total': 18, 'lead_status': '2'},
           {'total': 18, 'lead_status': '9'}, 
           {'total': 18, 'lead_status': '8'}, 
           {'total': 16, 'lead_status': '15'}, 
           {'total': 17, 'lead_status': '14'}
         ]

list_2 = [
           {'total': 18, 'lead_status': '2'}, 
           {'total': 22, 'lead_status': '9'},
           {'total': 18, 'lead_status': '8'},
           {'total': 16, 'lead_status': '15'}, 
           {'total': 17, 'lead_status': '14'}
         ]
```

`lead_status` always have unique value and the order of dictionary in lists might or might not be same.

I want to check that for each `lead_status` the `total` value is same or not in both lists

**Example**

For `lead_status : '2'` both the lists have same `total` which is 18 then it returns `True`

For `lead_status : '9'` both the lists have different `total` which is 18 in `list_1` but 22 in `list_2`. So it returns `False`.

I have tried the answer in this solution: [Comparing 2 lists consisting of dictionaries with unique keys in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845369/comparing-2-lists-consisting-of-dictionaries-with-unique-keys-in-python/9845430#9845430)

Please help to solve this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what would be the desired output, the fun will return a list o boolean? a dict of total:boolean?

Comment: desired o/p can be in boolean. Because I am checking that for each ```lead_status``` the ```total``` is same or not on both list

Comment: `[list_1[idx]['total'] == list_2[idx]['total'] for idx in range(len(list_1))]` Why this won't work?

Comment: Would both lists be always going to be sorted in the same "lead_status" asc order? Would these lists be of the same size all the time?

Comment: `[x['total']==y['total'] for x,y in zip(list_1,list_2)]` but that completely drops the other keys. If they're the same for both list that'll work, but your data is strange.

Comment: Also, what have you tried so for?

Comment: @alecxe No, both list will not be sorted but the size will remain same

Comment: Sorry.. My question was not clear but now I have edited my question..

Comment: @AmitTripathi I have tried this ans: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9845430/6695297

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava does my post answers your question?

Comment: @AmitTripathi Yes... It works... thanks alot.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from your question, this should work:

```
In [25]: dict_1 = {l['lead_status']:l['total'] for l in list_1}

In [26]: dict_2 = {l['lead_status']:l['total'] for l in list_2}

In [28]: {k: (dict_2[k] == v) for k, v in dict_1.items()}
Out[28]: {'14': True, '15': True, '2': True, '8': True, '9': False}
```

This first creates a dict of key equal to the value `lead_status` and the value of total and then compares the dict created from both the lists.

*Though, in case your 'lead_status' key have the same value than that gets overwritten.*

Comment: This is exactly I want.. You got my point... So can you help me to edit this question. So that the chances for more -ve vote will be less

Comment: ```lead_status``` key will be unique in my case... Thanks... :)

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Glad, it helped :) I have edited your question to show an example of [how to ask a good question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always, show what have you tried. Paste the minimum but all required part of the code with any stack trace. This helps the community in answering the question.

Comment: Thanks. I will be much more clear next time. :)