# python difference between 2 lists of dictionaries by a key

Tags: python, arrays, lambda

I have 2 lists of dictionaries similar to below:

```
a = [
     {'username': 'user1', 'is_admin': False}, 
     {'username': 'user2', 'is_admin': True}, 
     {'username': 'user3', 'is_admin': True}
    ]

b = [
     {'username': 'user1', 'is_admin': False}, 
     {'username': 'user2', 'is_admin': False}, 
     {'username': 'user4', 'is_admin': True}
    ]
```

Now, I want to compare these 2 lists and get the data something like this:

```
difference between a and b =
{'added': 
    [{'username': 'user4', 'is_admin': True}], 
 'removed': 
    [{'username': 'user3', 'is_admin': True}], 
 'updated': 
    [{'username': 'user2', 'is_admin': False}], 
  'unchanged': 
    [{'username': 'user1', 'is_admin': False}]]
 }
```

Explanation: user4 is added to b list, user 3 is removed from b list and value of user2 is updated (is_admin field) and user1 is unchanged.

I have an option to loop through one of the list and search for each "username" key in other list. But that doesn't seems efficient option (Searching all through array in every loop).

Is there an efficient way to solve this?

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845369/comparing-2-lists-consisting-of-dictionaries-with-unique-keys-in-python)?

Comment: Yes, I had tried this. But that doesn't work for the cases like "updated" where for username "user2" value has changed from is_admin true to false.

Comment: These are *lists* with *dictionaries*. Python != Javascript

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok.

Comment: try `unittest.TestCase.assertListEqual` method. It provides verbose diffs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried the following code and it worked.
what i have done here is find the dict that are present in b and absent in a(added list). then the removed dict which are present in a but not in b(removed list). since 'user2' in a and b are not exactly same(updated) the data of 'user2' will be present in both added and removed list so in the next step i found the list of usernames that are present in both added and removed list and then have removed dict from added and removed list that has the usernames present in the updated username list.

```
a = [
     {'username': 'user1', 'is_admin': False}, 
     {'username': 'user2', 'is_admin': True}, 
     {'username': 'user3', 'is_admin': True}
    ]

b = [
     {'username': 'user1', 'is_admin': False}, 
     {'username': 'user2', 'is_admin': False}, 
     {'username': 'user4', 'is_admin': True}
    ]

added = [i for i in b if i not in a]
removed = [i for i in a if i not in b]
unchanged = [i for i in a if i in b]
updated_usernames = [i 
                    for i in list(i['username'] for i in added) 
                    if i in list(i['username'] for i in removed)]
updated = []
for i in added:
    if i['username'] in updated_usernames:
        added.remove(i)
        updated.append(i)
for i in removed:
    if i['username'] in updated_usernames:
        removed.remove(i)

difference_between_a_and_b = {'added': added, 
 'removed': removed, 
 'updated': updated, 
  'unchanged': unchanged
 }

print(difference_between_a_and_b)
```

Output i got
[image]

Comment: thanks... seems working. I will test it more tomorrow.

Comment: You are welcome.. If you find any issue while testing please add that as a comment I will try to fix it .

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the lists for sure. To make it efficient, you can remove checked elements from the first two lists (or copy of them) and break the nested loop once an element is found to process. That will significantly increase efficiency I think.

Example(pseudocode):

```
while a or b:
  x = pop(a)
  y = pop(b)
  # compare x and y (try to use built-in methods such as map, filter etc. to make it fast)
  # append to one of the differences dictionary's list
```